# How do I verify a number is from a specific country, specific network company, and specific regional code

Tags: php

I want to write a code that verifies a number is from a specific country. Let's say I just want to take numbers from the USA so that means the code will start with +1, and specific area or state so let's say 423 or from a specific network company. I need help with this

Comment: You can hard-code the filters you needed. Then just check with `if/else` statement

Answer (score 0):

I would normally recommend

[Googles libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

which I use myself, but as it's PHP this is their referred PHP clone

[libphonenumber-for-php](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)